Manual way to trigger click event on react element
let clickReactElement = (elem) => {
     const event = new Event('click', { bubbles: true })
     elem.dispatchEvent(event);
     for (key in elem) {
     if (key.startsWith("__reactProps")) {
      elem[key].onClick(event);
     }
}

This code works in the console, but doesn't work when you run it in the actual code. How do I find the __reactProps or __reactEventHandlers via code?
Please tell me why this is？
Let me tell you the background of the problem: I'm working on a browser plug-in that injects script into the target website (react.js), and part of the script is to manipulate the button on the landing page including clicks. onClick in the __reactPropsxxxx property of the DOM element successfully executed the click, but this only works in the console, I execute the same code in the js file I can't find the __reactProps or __reactEventHandlers related attributes

Let me tell you the background of the problem: I'm working on a browser plug-in that injects script into the target website (react.js), and part of the script is to manipulate the button on the landing page including clicks. onClick in the __reactPropsxxxx property of the DOM element successfully executed the click, but this only works in the console, I execute the same code in the js file I can't find the __reactProps or __reactEventHandlers related attributes

Have you tried to use react refs ?
For example:
import React from 'react'

const Button = () => {
    const buttonEl = React.useRef()

    // Manual click over here (pragmatically)
    buttonEl.current.click()

    return <button ref={buttonEl}>Click me </button>
}


Wouldn't that be buttonEl.current.click()?

You should also add a check if buttonEl.current exists or not since the ref may not attach itself to the component immediately

Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. Please take a look at the updated question. Thank you for your response.

So if I understand it correctly:

You are targeting the website that's written in React
That means the website has already been transpiled into native JavaScript, and hosted somewhere

You are not directly writing code in this React project
That means the original source code, most likely written in JSX


Then you probably need to write your code asynchronously, that means you probably need to use defer attribute to load your code after the page finishes parsing, or place your code at the end of the HTML file, so that your code has the access to the entire DOM when it's executed.
If you viewed the source of the website you are targeting, it will not contain the element you are trying to find, but <div id="app-root"></div>, that's why you cannot find the element if the JS snippet you write doesn't run asynchronously. The DOM element is only available after the entire page is finished render, and that's why the code in console can find the element.

Here, In the below code snippet, you can pass any react element and the onClick event will be triggered for that element.
This might work for you. Try it out.
import React from 'react';
import { findDOMNode } from 'react-dom';

const clickReactElement = (element) => {

  const node = findDOMNode (element);
  
  if (node) {

    const event = new MouseEvent ('click', { bubbles: true });
    
    node.dispatchEvent (event);
  }
};


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
